# Why are edits to my css file not showing up? Django

Tags: css, django

So I am noticing that my css changes are not being reflected. I did a hard-reload and cleared the cache but still nothing. Like I can literally delete the css file and my badge which I'm trying to edit is still there... it only goes away once I take it off of base.html directly. So what is going on here? I have a static folder in my app, with a css folder and then my css/notification file. I tried doing collectstatic through terminal but that doesn't do anything. Also, I already have my `load static` tag in my html.

**settings.py**

```
     STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
"/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static",
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dating_app/media')
```

**settings.py/installed_apps**

```
 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
```

**project urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('dating_app.urls', namespace= 'dating_app')),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: Do you have django.contrib.staticfiles in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings file? If so, can you share the code parts with the steps describes on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ document?

Comment: @DenizKaplan Yes, it's already there. Ok, edited it. Is that what you need?

Comment: Can you change STATICFILES_DIR to STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: Does it work? If it is, please let me know so I can create an answer with a few more details to help others to solve their problems.

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the key for the static files directories. So you should keep that change. Can you confirm that css folder and notification.css file in the folder `/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static`? And d yoou have DEBUG True in your settings file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use STATICFILES_DIRS instead of STATICFILES_DIR.
also write ALL PATH in STATICFILES_DIR like this.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  ]
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference